# How to align text corresponds to text within the above line?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

My attempt was to use `tabular`:

```
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
   Let & $M_1$ recognize $A_1$, where $M_1 = (Q_1, \Sigma, \delta_1, q_1, F_1)$, & \\
   & $M_2$ recognize $A_2$, where $M_1 = (Q_2, \Sigma, \delta_2, q_2, F_2)$. &
\end{tabular}
```

However, there are several spaces between `Let` and `M_1`, how could I get rid of these spaces? Furthermore, is this a standard way to align text? If I want to be the most flexible, i.e. editing on the fly, which approach should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this, and it depends on your preference, or even how big of a structure you are working with. For example, still using `tabular`, you could consider using

```
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{@{}l@{\ }}}
  Let & $M_1$ recognize $A_1$, & where $M_1=(Q_1,\Sigma,\delta_1,q_1,F_1)$, \\
  & $M_2$ recognize $A_2$, & where $M_1=(Q_2,\Sigma,\delta_2,q_2,F_2)$.
\end{tabular}
```

This creates 3 identical, left-aligned columns (via `*{3}{..l..}`), where each column has the formatting `@{}l@{\ }`. This formatting adds a regular space `{\  }` between columns, and remove the column separation at the beginning of each column (via `@{}`).

[image: Horizontal alignment of stuff]

---

Alternatively you could use boxes (and other structures) to align text components. Here's an example:

```
\usepackage{calc}%
...
Let $M_1$ recognize $A_1$, where $M_1=(Q_1,\Sigma,\delta_1,q_1,F_1)$, \\
\phantom{Let} $M_2$ recognize \makebox[\widthof{$A_1$}][c]{$A_2$}, where $M_1=(Q_2,\Sigma,\delta_2,q_2,F_2)$.
```

Although somewhat superfluous, I hope it demonstrates the principle. You can use

```
\phantom{<stuff>}
```

to typeset a box exactly the size of `<stuff>`, without actually typesetting `<stuff>` itself. Also, using the [`calc` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/calc), you can define boxes of specific width using `\widthof{<stuff>}` in conjunction with

```
\makebox[<width>][<horizontal alignment>]{<stuff>}
```

I'm sure there are other (perhaps more elegant) ways as well.

Comment: Many thanks for a very detailed solution ;).